# Projecting selection from large data set using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, geoprocessing, performance

I have a large data set X(x1-xn) from which I must select consecutively the attributes A(a1-an) from X.fieldsSRC or X.fieldDST and project the selections.

I have a functioning arcpy script that does the following:

```
<inside loop incrementing n>
#proj_sr is defined here but omitted
where_clause = fieldSRC = n OR fieldDST = n #simplified for webparser

#create a new feature class based on selection
arcpy.Select_analysis('input', 'temp1', where_clause)
#project selection
arcpy.Project_management('temp1', 'temp2', proj_sr)

#PERFORM OPERATION ON PROJECTED SELECTION

#append selection, and project to destination SR
arcpy.Append_management('temp2', 'final_output')

#we must delete rows from source files otherwise we will treat them each twice
#create layer file in order to select and delete specific rows
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('input', 'layerfile', where_clause)
#delete rows selected above in layer file
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management('layerfile')
<end of loop>
```

This works. In my mind there should be a manner to do the following which would be more efficient.

```
<inside loop incrementing n>
#proj_sr is defined here but omitted
where_clause = fieldSRC = n OR fieldDST = n #simplified for webparser

#create layer file in order to select and delete specific rows
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('input', 'layerfile', where_clause)
#project ACTUAL selection rather than a complete shapefile as was done earlier
arcpy.Project_management('layerfile', 'temp2', proj_sr)

#PERFORM OPERATION ON PROJECTED SELECTION

#delete rows selected above in layer file
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management('layerfile')
<end of loop>
```

Obviously the arcpy.Project_management() function does not operate in the second code example.
It's a rather large data set ('input') and recreating the feature class based on the selection each time does not seem efficient/necessary. It works but it is not fast.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I think you should pursue your second code example further.  MakeFeatureLayer accepts an SQL expression and Project accepts a feature layer so I am thinking it should work unless there was an code error there when you tested that.  Perhaps get just those few lines of code out into a separate test and report back on what issue is arising from it.

Comment: The problem I'm encountering using the desired method (the second code block) is that Project is selecting the full source data set rather than the layer selection.

The arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management operation has created the layer 'layerfile' from 'input' successfully and selected the desired x rows. When I pass 'layerfile' to arcpy.Project_management it projects all the rows from 'input'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

The code below should work using the file geodatabase that Cyrille posted to the Esri Discussion Forum.

```
import arcpy

prjString = "PROJCS['World_Mercator',GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',0.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-20037700 -30198300 10000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;0.001;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(r"C:/Support/Cyrille/MFL_Test.gdb/FlightPaths",r"C:/Support/Cyrille/FlightPaths.shp","#","0","0","0")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"C:/Support/Cyrille/FlightPaths.shp","YVR_layer",'"src" = ' + "'YVR'")

arcpy.Project_management("YVR_layer", r"C:/Support/Cyrille/MFL_Test.gdb/YVR_Proj", prjString)
```

What I found is that my original code made the layer on a shapefile while Cyrille was making it on a file geodatabase feature class.  To workaround what I think is either a MakeFeatureLayer bug or a Project bug what I did was to copy the feature class to a shapefile before performing those two steps on it.  That way the where clause is respected.

I suspect the workaround will not be desirable for Cyrille so the next step will be to see if this bug has been reported previously and to report it if not.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I just ran the test below which uses MakeFeatureLayer_management to apply an SQL expression to the underlying dataset (of 31 polylines), and then uses Project_management to project that layer (of one polyline).  The results is a feature class of one projected polyline.  So it looks like what you are trying to do in your second code example should work, unless your where_clause is not evaluating correctly.  Consequently, my recommendation is to double-check that your where_clause is working.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Temp/test.shp","test_Layer",'"ID" = 555')

arcpy.Project_management("test_Layer","C:/Temp/test.gdb/projectedFC","PROJCS['GDA_1994_Australia_Albers',GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Albers'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',132.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',-18.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',-36.0],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]","#","GEOGCS['GCS_GDA_1994',DATUM['D_GDA_1994',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")
```

Comment: I created a super simple example using my data and posted the geodatabase and code on the [esri forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57976-MakeFeatureLayer-where_clause-selection-not-maintained-during-projection?p=199629#post199629). I agree and believe it should work. It clearly is not though. I used the python window so I can clearly see that the 'where_clause' is functioning correctly. Give it a spin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a `SearchCursor` and [setting the spatial reference on it](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_a_cursor_s_spatial_reference/002z0000001w000000/) so it reprojects the results on the fly? Code below straight outta the help:

```
import arcpy

desc = arcpy.Describe("d:/base/data.gdb/latlongbnd")

# Create search cursor. Use the spatial reference object from the
#   described feature class so geometries are returned in decimal degrees.
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("d:/base/data.gdb/buildings", "", desc.spatialReference)
```

Comment: I do not need to iterate through a list. I need to select 1-200 rows of spatial data from a file containing ~40,000 elements and project just the selection. While iterating may not be slower than a selection (although I hope it is), the projection of all the elements may well be. I would have to do some timing tests but I am unsure that this would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

SearchCursor takes a "where" clause - it's the best way to deal with a subset of records.

Comment: Could you please explain the answer with detail?